# APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back

Tags: apt, postfix, purge

I am getting the error `W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (0 vs 5). Affected packages: postfixadmin:amd64`

[EDIT] full output:

```
root@mail:~# sudo apt purge postfixadmin && sudo apt update
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  libpq5 php-imap postgresql-client postgresql-client-12 postgresql-client-common wwwconfig-common
Verwenden Sie »sudo apt autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen.
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
  postfixadmin*
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 1 zu entfernen und 1 nicht aktualisiert.
Nach dieser Operation werden 3.916 kB Plattenplatz freigegeben.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] J
W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (0 vs 5).
   Affected packages: postfixadmin:amd64
OK:1 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Holen:2 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Holen:3 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]  
Holen:4 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]       
OK:5 https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu focal InRelease             
Es wurden 328 kB in 2 s geholt (169 kB/s).
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Aktualisierung für 1 Paket verfügbar. Führen Sie »apt list --upgradable« aus, um es anzuzeigen.
```

The problem appears when I try to purge or install a package

How can I fix that?

Comment: Edit your question and include the exact commands that you are using and the complete output of each command. Also include `sudo apt update`

Comment: @Nmath I updated the post

Comment: please also `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Comment: @nobody The output: `root@mail:~# dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'
root@mail:~# `

Comment: Possible insight here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1647638